# How to call the AutoML Vision model prediction from an iOS app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on Google Cloud AutoML Vision Object Detection.
I'm following the below tutorial https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/prepare

As I want a custom model I created a new dataset and trained it.During training it asked to choose between **Cloud Hosted** or **Edge** for my model. I have chosen **Cloud Hosted**.

To make use of this Cloud Hosted model/to make predictions of an image we need to make Rest API calls from our end. In the tutorial it is mentioned how to make these Rest API calls in various client libraries but not in **Swift**. I want to know how to make this Rest API Call through Swift from an iOS app.

How to execute the REST API?

Given info on Rest API

request.json

```
{
 "payload": {
 "image": {
   "imageBytes": "YOUR_IMAGE_BYTE"
  },
 }
}
```

Execute the request

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/drughk-9747d/locations/us-central1/models/ICN6566958205491349320:predict -d @request.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the [Cloud Vision Swift Sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/ios/Swift), specifically in the [ImagePickerViewController.swift](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/ios/Swift/imagepicker/ImagePickerViewController.swift) where the createRequest method calls Google API for ImageDetection using the API_KEY to authenticate the request.

Comment: I already had a look at this sample. Making use of API_KEY  is an old approach is what I heard and also the GitHub repo is last updated 3 years ago. Now we should be implementing making use of Service account it seems. Do you have any idea on how to implement this using Service account?

Comment: Oh I see, then refer to [Setting up a token service for iOS apps - Calling the token service from the client app](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/token-service-oauth) and the [Auth Library for Swift](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-swift), specifically the [FCMTokenProvider.getToken](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-swift/blob/master/Sources/OAuth2/FCMTokenProvider/FCMTokenProvider.swift#L69)